# Yield from nested loops in scala

Tags: scala

I have an array of arrays and I'd like to define a function which yield every single elements. Something like this:

```
def foo(l:MyList) = {
    for (e1 <- l.sub_list) {
        for(e2 <- e1.sub_list) {
            yield e2
        }
    }
}

def bar(l:MyList) = {
  foo(l).map(a => {
    //.. body
  })
}
```

Is it possible in scala?

Comment: I you code, where did `l1` come from? And example of what goes into the function and what goes out would be nice.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I fixed it.

Comment: @badnack could you please include the definition of `MyList` and and example of an input and the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am now assuming the `l.sub_list` would return an array nested within `l`. `MyList` could look like:

```
type MyList[A] = Array[Array[A]]
```

And `foo` could be defined as:

```
def foo[A](l: MyList[A]) = for {
  l1 <- l
  e <- l1
} yield e
```

Is this the expected result?

```
scala> foo(Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6), Array(7,8,9)))
Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

---

**EDIT**: added `bar` to the question

One possible implementation of `bar`

```
def bar(l: MyList[Int]) = foo(l).map(_ * 10)
```

expected result:

```
scala> bar(Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6), Array(7,8,9)))
Array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *yield*, You can use `List.flatten`.

For example:

`val l = List(List(1, 2), List(3), List(4,5))
val f = l.flatten // f: List[Int] = List(1,2,3,4,5)`